# Daemon Socket server in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, daemon

I have successfully created a C program which runs an infinite loop waiting for a connecting through sockets. 
I would like to make it a daemon and be able to start and stop it. How can I do it? What changes should I do to my code to run in the background?

Comment: Read `APUE, Stevens and Rago, chapter 13, Daemon Processes`.

Comment: Which OS is your program running on ?

Answer (score 2):

The classic tasks required to become a daemon are:

1. Change the working directory to the root, so that your daemon does not pin another mount;
2. Call `fork()` and have the parent exit, so that the process is not a process group leader;
3. Redirect standard input, standard output and standard error to `/dev/null`;
4. Call `setsid()` to make the process a session group leader of a new session with no controlling terminal.

Without error-checking:

```
chdir("/);

if (fork() > 0)
    _exit();

close(0);
close(1);
close(2);
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
dup(0);
dup(0);

setsid();
```

On Linux, glibc provides a `daemon()` helper function to do these tasks.

Comment: daemon() exists on non-linux systems as well although it isn't portable.

Comment: This answer does not ignore SIGHUP while calling setsid to prevent parent session from to prevent the group leader's calls to _exit(2) from terminating the child process

Answer (score 1):

To run a c program as daemon you need to do the following steps.

```
// Create child process
process_id = fork();

//unmask the file mode
umask(0);

//change the directory as your home directory
strcpy(home,"HOME");                                                                                   
home=getenv(home);
chdir(home) ;


//set new session
sid = setsid();
close(STDIN_FILENO); open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
close(STDOUT_FILENO); open("/dev/null", O_RDWR); 
close(STDERR_FILENO); open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
```

Comment: this is wrong: change to / instead of HOME.  umask not required.